# How to run the graph-node in the rinkeby test rpc

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, thegraph, thegraph.com

I am trying to write a subgraph for the contract which is deployed in the rinkeby test network.

for that I need to run the graph-node in the same rinkeby test network.

With the reference of the below repo

https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node

I am running it in my local machine using the below cargo command

```
cargo run -p graph-node --release --  --postgres-url postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/graph-node  --ethereum-rpc 'rinkeby:https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2a46ac7cdb4c44acac4de87dadfd6e39'  --ipfs 127.0.0.1:5001
```

I used infura.io for getting the rinkeby rpc url.

but its throws an error 401 Unauthorized. I don't know where i am making the mistake.

[image]

I m unable to connect the rinkeby network.

Kindly please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Infura endpoint is not set up correctly, check your project ID and the permissions you have set up in your account, some examples can be found here or via your Infura login: https://infura.io/docs/gettingStarted/chooseaNetwork

Answer (score 0):

I did a blunder mistake in the command.

removing the single quote in the rpc url resolves the issue

```
cargo run -p graph-node --release -- --postgres-url postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/graph-node --ethereum-rpc rinkeby:https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2a46ac7cdb4c44acac4de87dadfd6e39 --ipfs 127.0.0.1:5001
```